# Object is undefined while have data

Tags: reactjs

I have an array contains object look like below

```
[
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "123", isDelete: false, name: "afd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    },
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "123", isDelete: false, name: "ffd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    },
]
```

This is when I filter in it

```
brands.filter(brand => {
      console.log(brand);// like above data
      console.log(brand.data);// show brand.data
      console.log(brand.data._id);//error brand.data is not defined
})
```

I already try

```
brands.filter(brand => {
      let a = brand.data;
      console.log(a._id);// error a is null
})
```

I need to get `brand.data.name` like when I loop it need to print `afd` and `ffd`.

Comment: `filter` is array method, why and how you are using it for object?

Comment: javascript filter works on array not on objects.

Comment: My bad `brands` is an array contains object.

Comment: I think he actually has an array but maybe some of the elements in that array don't have the structure as the others.

Comment: @someoneuseless make sure that all the elements in the `brands` array have the same structure.

Comment: @someoneuseless can you update you `brands` array in question?

Comment: It is not clear, what exactly `brand` is and how it relates with your object sample and furthermore, which exactly output you need to get.

Comment: I tested it, it work fine to me.

Comment: I update my question. The array get fetched by backend so I can't change its structure

Comment: @WesleyLoh could you help me with a fiddle I dont know how it can work

Comment: I cant see any error in your code, I try it with local var so it should work fine. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

As per your question if all you want to do is to log the value of `brand.data.name` then using `filter` doesn't make any sense.

You can just use `forEach` for that.

```js
const brands = [
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "123", isDelete: false, name: "afd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    },
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "123", isDelete: false, name: "ffd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    }
];

brands.forEach(brand => { console.log(brand.data.name) });
```

If you want to store the names in an array instead of just logging them then you can use `map` for that.

```js
const brands = [
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "123", isDelete: false, name: "afd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    },
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "123", isDelete: false, name: "ffd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    }
];

const brandNames = brands.map(brand => brand.data.name);
console.log(brandNames);
```

Comment: It s weird that it is working fine. Maybe it is because some problem when I fetch my data in.Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript filter works on array. So considering you want to filter your nested object(based on id) which is data, your code should be written like below-

```
const brands = [
    {
    _id: "12",
    data: { _id: "1", isDelete: false, name: "afd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    },
    {
    _id: "13",
    data: { _id: "2", isDelete: false, name: "ffd" },
    createdAt: "2020-04-11T08:38:15.966Z",
    shop_id: "sfd",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-27T02:07:12.271Z"
    },
]

const updatedBrands = brands.map(brand => {(
  ...brand, brand.data.filter(key => key._id === '1') 
}))
```

You have to first use javascript map method to iterate over the array and then you can filter your data object by id. Hope this helps.

Comment: the think is I want to get into data and name but still fail

Comment: Just replace ._id with data.

Comment: the `_id` in the `brands` array is a string but inside the filter, you used `brand._id === 12` which is only true when the value is 12 and type is number.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I added my answer assuming id is a number.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code and even if you don't have any, how is this an answer to what he asked? Why are you assuming that he's trying to filter by `_id`?